# Using Google Fonts in the windows boot image

Tags: windows, fonts, github

How do I install Google Fonts inside the boot image of my windows?
So that I am able to install/update all computers with the fonts pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the Google Fonts you wish from official [Google Fonts Github](https://github.com/google/fonts)
2. Download free version of [WindowReducer](https://www.winreducer.net/winreducer-ex-100.html) for creating a custom Windows installation image or
3. If your initial Windows image is in ISO format you may need to mount it to a virtual drive with the help of a software like [Virtual CloneDrive](https://www.elby.ch/en/products/vcd.html).
4. Follow the instructions on how to integrate objects

Alternative solution is [NTLite](https://www.ntlite.com/)

Adding the font files in the custom installation will be easy, however probably you may need to inform the pre-installed registry file about the activation of those font files.